# Как ограничить размер показываемой области у Яндекс карт?

Tags: api, react-native, карты, яндекс-карты, область-видимости

Доброго времени суток!

В мобильном приложении (React Native) для отображения информации используется оффлайн версия карты Яндекс Карт.
Хочу найти решение как ограничить отображаемую область показа только одним регионом или территорией по заданным координатам. Чтобы можно было также свободно рассматривать карту(увеличивать, уменьшать), но только в указанном "квадрате".  За пределами области ничего не должно отображаться.

p.s. Нечто похожее раньше было у 2GIS, когда можно было просматривать строго один регион.

Comment: У Яндекса нет оффлайн-версии карт, только в коммерческом MapKit такая возможность доступна. Потому едва ли тут без примера кода кто поймёт даже как именно вы запихнули карту в своё приложение, а соответственно и помочь не смогут. Добавьте подробностей в вопрос.

Comment: В коммерческом MapKit, как можно сделать ограничение по используемой области карты? Чтобы не размер контейнера или рамки был ограничен, а именно просматриваемой области.

Comment: Если вы знаете как сделать это в коммерческом MapKit, то такой вариант ответа устроит.

Comment: Грубо говоря, аналог https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/restrict_map_area, но в MapKit

Comment: Насколько знаю, встроенных методов подобных JS API в МапКите нет. Только если своё что-то реализовать пытаться.